# Как обойти xml дерево и сформировать новое дерево для Html?

Tags: c#

У меня есть xml код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas">


-<w:body>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="006C4437" w:rsidR="00113F3B">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Первый</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="006C4437" w:rsidR="006C4437">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Первый</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="006C4437" w:rsidR="006C4437">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="1"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Второй</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="00200659" w:rsidR="006C4437">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="1"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Второй</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="00200659" w:rsidR="00200659">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="1"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Второй</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="00200659" w:rsidR="00200659">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="2"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Третий</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="00D1536E" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="00200659" w:rsidR="00200659">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="2"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Третий</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="003161A0" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="003161A0" w:rsidR="003161A0">


-<w:pPr>

<w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>


-<w:numPr>

<w:ilvl w:val="2"/>

<w:numId w:val="6"/>

</w:numPr>

</w:pPr>


-<w:r>

<w:t>Третий</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>

<w:p w:rsidP="003161A0" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidR="003161A0"/>


-<w:p w:rsidP="003161A0" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidR="003161A0">


-<w:r>

<w:t>Текст</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="003161A0" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidR="003161A0">


-<w:r>

<w:t>Текст</w:t>

</w:r>

</w:p>


-<w:p w:rsidP="003161A0" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidR="003161A0">


-<w:r>

<w:t>Текст</w:t>

</w:r>

<w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0"/>

<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>

</w:p>

<w:p w:rsidP="003161A0" w:rsidRDefault="003161A0" w:rsidRPr="00255B60" w:rsidR="003161A0"/>


-<w:sectPr w:rsidRPr="00255B60" w:rsidR="003161A0">

<w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>

<w:pgMar w:gutter="0" w:footer="708" w:header="708" w:left="1701" w:bottom="1134" w:right="850" w:top="1134"/>

<w:cols w:space="708"/>

<w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>

</w:sectPr>

</w:body>

</w:document>
```

Как мне его обойти и сформировать дерево для формирования html текста? Использую OpenXMl

Comment: Есть такая штука - десереализация, а в вашем случае десереализация XML.

Comment: ещё как вариант, вы можете использовать XSLT преобразование, чтобы XML превратить в HTML